# Why won't slideDown() function work in JQuery event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have just started trying to learn JQuery event handling, and cannot seem to understand why this is happening.  I read through the section on event handling in the documentation, but I am still having trouble manipulating objects on the page from the event handler.  I get the basic idea of event bubbling up through the DOM, and have been successful i attaching primitive functions that operate on the specific object to which they are attached, or which can launch an alert.  Below is the HTML, CSS, and Javascript, and the trouble is specifically with this handler:

```
    $("#picTwo").click(function() {
        
        alert("Handle for left arrow");
        $("#picOne").slideDown(3000, linear, function()
        {
            alert("Why doesn't it work?");
        });
```

Here is the full code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#leftButton").click(function() {
    alert("Handle for left button click()");
    $(this).hide();
    $("#picOne").slideDown(3000, linear, function() {
      alert("Why doesn't it work?");
    });
  });

  $("#blockRed").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });
  $("#blockBlue").click(function() {
    alert("Handle for blue block");
  });
  $("#blockGreen").click(function() {
    alert("Handle for green block");
  });
  $("#picOne").click(function() {
    alert("Handle for right  arrow");

  });

  $("#picTwo").click(function() {
    alert("Handle for left arrow");
    $("#picOne").slideDown(3000, linear, function() {
      alert("Why doesn't it work?");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#picOne {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

#picTwo {
  float: left;
}

.friendImg {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  border: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 25%;
}

.lightRedBox {
  background-color: rgb(23, 0, 0);
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  border: #09C;
  border-width: thin;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

#blackBox {
  background: black;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}

#blockBlue {
  background: blue;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}

#blockRed {
  background: red;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}

#blockGreen {
  background: green;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bonsai Exquisite - Gallery</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/galleryCSS.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Add icon library -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="blackBox">
    <div class="lightRedBox" id="firstBox">
      <h4 class="boxTitle">Bonsai </h4>
      <img src="images/coolFilteBonsai.jpg" alt="bonsai image" id="leftFriendImage" class="friendImg">
      <p class="boxBlurb">This associatin has been assisting local bonsai associations for over fifty years, and has contributed to the larger pattern of bonsai growth globally. In the past five years, the association has been dealing with blah blah blsah blah.....</p>

      <button type="button" id="leftButton" class="leftClassButton" name='leftClassName' onMouseOver="leftBotWinShine()" onMouseOut="botWinShineout()" onClick="closeLeftBox()">Close  Me!</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="vanishing">

    <div id="blockBlue">
    </div>
    <div id="blockRed">
    </div>
    <div id="blockGreen">
    </div>

  </div>

  <img src="images/images/rightPage.png" id="picOne">
  <img src="images/images/leftPage.png" id="picTwo">
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks for your time and help, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `linear` needs to be in quotes.

Comment: Thank you, that will save me another headache :)  But, having changed the code and added the quotes, it now prints the alert message, but the slideDown doesn't occur

Comment: there should be error , check your browser console. As observed by @Barmar linear is not defined it should be string ``` "linear" ```.

Comment: @MuhammadSaquibShaikh I already pointed that out above, he said it still doesn't work. I just reproduced it with a copy of the stack snippet.

Comment: I received errors that pointed out all the undefined onClick and onMouseovers in the button tag, so I pulled those out, but still...I get the alert box in Chrome and Firefox, but the slideDown effect doesn't occur

Comment: slideDown cannot work if content is already visible. So you need to change your css to display:none for #picOne or else add ```hide()``` method to make it appear like slide down.

Comment: I guess what I meant to say is that the function is working properly, otherwise the alert wouldn't be displaying, but I am not seeing the slideDown effect occur on #picOne

Comment: I see.  Thank you.  That solves a lot.  I don't know why, but I had it in my head that I could slide an image OUT of visibility with slideDown, had it backwards......

Comment: ```$("#picTwo").click(function() {
    $("#picOne").hide().slideDown(3000, "linear", function() {
      alert("Why doesn't it work?");
    });
  });``` replace your code with this and it will work

Comment: Thanks, both of you for taking the time to help me.  I don't see a way to attribute the answer to someone in a comment....

Answer (score 0):

`slideDown()` used for animate in some content which is not visible. Here your content is already visible so `slideDown()` seems not working although it is working but cannot be seen. To get animation you need to hide the element by changing css `display:none` or else add `.hide()` method before `slideDown()` like

```
$("#picTwo").click(function() {
$("#picOne").hide().slideDown(3000, "linear", function() {
  alert("Why doesn't it work?");
});
});
```